# f# generic type comparison

Tags: generics, f#, types

I'm trying to figure out if an obj returned from a call is of a certain type.  Here is my code:

```
type MyType<'T>= 
    val mutable myArr : array
    val mutable id : int
    val mutable value : 'T
```

and in some method that has MyType in scope...

```
let a  = someFunThatReturnsObj()   // a could be of type MyType
```

How do I figure out if a is of type MyType?

Comment: Hmmm, run-time type checking? Do you know what types your method returns? If so, maybe you can wrap the type in a type-safe union and use pattern matching instead, maybe your types in that function can expose a common interface? There are lots of things you can do to avoid a run-time type check.

Comment: What if you don't know what the types return are?  See my post below AS T1<T2<int>> is Different thean T1<T2<float>> what if you only care about the object being of T1 regardless of the other specifics?

Answer (score 6):

```
match a with
| :? MyType<int> as mt -> // it's a MyType<int>, use 'mt'
| _ -> // it's not
```

If you care about just a `MyType<X>` for some unknown `X`, then

```
let t = a.GetType()
if t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typedefof<MyType<int>> then
    // it is
```

Comment: It looks like I have another issue. It appears someFunThatReturnsObj() returns 'U. Using your first suggested method, I get: "This runtime coercion or type test from type 'U to MyType<int> involves an indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. Runtime type tests are not allowed on some types. Further type annotations are needed."

Comment: Just call 'box' first, then.   "match box a with..."

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'box' Brian?

Comment: Call the `box` function, which upcasts its argument to type `obj`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is that simple (remember I am f# naive) consider the follwoing scenario where

1) we are using generics on multiple types 
2) we don't have the type information for an object so it comes in to a function as type obj, like in some of the .NET datacontract / serialization libraries

I reworked my proposal to use reflection:

```
type SomeType<'A> = { 
        item : 'A 
    } 


type AnotherType<'A> = { 
    someList : 'A list 
} 

let test() = 

    let getIt() : obj =  
        let results : SomeType<AnotherType<int>> = { item = { someList = [1;2;3] }} 
        upcast results 

    let doSomething (results : obj) =  
        let resultsType = results.GetType()
        if resultsType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typedefof<SomeType<_>> then 
            let method = resultsType.GetMethod("get_item")
            if method <> null then
                let arr = method.Invoke(results, [||]) 
                if arr.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() = typedefof<AnotherType<_>> then 
                    printfn "match" 

    getIt() |> doSomething
```

Seems like there should be more natural way of doing this...

Comment: This is great for figuring out if results falls into my desired SomeType<AnotherType<'T>> category.  The problem I still face is casting and using results as SomeType<AnotherType<System.Object>>.  I have control over everything 'T could be.  Can anyone suggest a way of doing this perhaps by using a common interface for all objects 'T could be?  Perhaps a common superclass?